Aggregate Error in Custom Hook Using React, Node.js, Express, MongoDB, and Socket.io
I'm working on a small chat application using Node.js, React, Express, MongoDB, and Socket.io. I created a custom hook to fetch user conversations, but I'm encountering an error related to aggregation.

AggregateError
  at internalConnectMultiple
  at afterConnectMultiple

here's the code,
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

const useGetConversations = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getConversations = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            try {
                const res = await fetch("/api/users");
                const data = await res.json();
                if (data.error) {
                    throw new Error(data.error);
                }
                setConversations(data);
            } catch (error) {
                toast.error(error.message);
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };

        getConversations();
    }, []);

    return { loading, conversations };
};

export default useGetConversations;


Additional Information:

The API endpoint /api/users is supposed to return a list of user conversations in JSON format.
I'm using react-toastify for error notifications.
The backend is built with Node.js, Express, MongoDB, and Socket.io.

What might be causing the AggregateError in my custom hook?
How can I debug and resolve this issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What's the error?

Aggregate error at internalConnectMultiple, at afterConnectMultiple

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AggregateError
an AggregateError holds multiple errors thrown at once.  you'll want to examine its "errors" array for specific details on each.  i would assume it's an issue with the api call, not your hook.
